# CamelConfiguration deprecated and removed

Tags: spring, apache-camel, spring-camel

I'm using camel with this class in a non spring boot project :

```
org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration;
```

I'm in camel 3.14.1

When i want to update camel to 3.16.0 or more, this class was removed

I find solution to replace this class by using camel-spring-boot-starter but i'm not in spring-boot app...

For now i have force camel to 3.16.0 and force add this dependency:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
    <version>3.14.1</version>
  </dependency>
```

It work but i want to remove this... any solution?

Thanks

Comment: Can you switch to Spring Boot? The Camel developers [recommend Spring Boot as the replacement for camel-spring-javaconfig](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@camel.apache.org/msg65203.html).

Comment: @ChinHuang no this app is under tomcat and no migration planned...so i think why not ensure compatibility for all that can't migrate to spring-boot for now...

Comment: Spring Boot can [create a war file](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.traditional-deployment.war) which can be deployed in Tomcat.